# symfony2 only anonymous for login

Tags: php, symfony

I want make my login route restricted for logged users ,

> security.yml

```
security:
encoders:

    Site\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Users:
        algorithm: md5
        iterations: 0
        encode_as_base64:   false

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
             users:
                ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
    administrators:
        entity: { class: SiteAdminBundle:Users , property: username}

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false


    secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Demo Area"
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
        provider: administrators
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

my login fucntion:

```
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(
            SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
        );
    } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = '';
    }

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);

    return $this->render(
        'SiteSecurityBundle:Default:login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
}
```

and problem is it work , for example for /admin only ROLE_ADMIN have access there and ROLE_USER no. but /login if i'm logged or not i can access it , in symfony2 develop tools i see i'm anonymous and stel i'm logged ... i stel have no ideea

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://henrik.bjrnskov.dk/symfony2-anonymous-users-access

Comment: this is intersting but i don't think is good idea .

Comment: Why do you want to deny access to /login for authenticated users in the first place?

Comment: because is more logic , if you are logged you don't need access register or log in ,if follow there tutorial maibey will be problem with IS_ANONYMOUS from symfony const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to limit the user access to some resource.
Below you will see 2 of this methods:

1) with **SensioFrameworkExtraBundle** (is included in symfony2 full-stack version) installed you can use [annotations for controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#annotations-for-controllers) like this

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

2) **without** SensioFrameworkExtraBundle annotations

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class YourController extends Controller
    {
        public function loginAction(Request $request)
        {
            if (true === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException('Unable to access this page!');

                # or you can do also a redirect instead of exception
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
```

[as explained in the docs here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-securing-controller) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/securing_services.html)